# Why would a source file have the execute bit set?

Tags: permissions, source

In the standard library for ecliptic curve cryptography one of the C source files has the executable bit set, qv:

[image]

As you can see there are multiple C files, but only the secp2561k1.c file is executable. This is just as I downloaded it. Why would just this one source code file have its execute bits set?

Comment: Just a guess, I’d say it’s accidental.

Comment: @StephenKitt If this was an obscure piece of code from somebody's personal project I would buy that, but this is a major library used by a lot of people for mission-critical purposes.

Comment: Even for a major library, the release process in many, many cases is just `tar czf` in the developer's directory (perhaps codified as `make dist`).

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes, that seems logical, also see Chazelas' comment to the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no reason for a C source file to be executable.  This may sometimes happen if the file has been transferred from or through a non-Unix operating system.

You may safely remove the execute bit if you wish:

```
$ chmod a-x secp256k1.c
```

Comment: There are two other C files in the same directory. Why would just this one particular file have the execute bit set? The file is marked as executable in the repository.

Comment: @TylerDurden It's most likely just by accident. If you really want to go to the bottom with it, then contact the original authors.

Comment: The x bit was added (for that file and another one) in [that commit](https://github.com/peterdettman/secp256k1/commit/0f9e69db555ea35b90f49fa48925c366261452ec). Most probably an accident like the working copy was on a NTFS file system mounted on a Unix-like system...

Comment: The [2 only commits by that user](https://github.com/peterdettman/secp256k1/commits/master?author=bgorlick) do add `x` bits, so it's just a case of that user having an issue with their working copy. It's not a big issue. Just looks untidy